# Correct sentence structure via javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

Below I have a `sentance` and `desiredResult` for the `sentance`. Using the `pattern` below I can snag the `t T` that needs to be changed to `t, t` but I don't know where to go further.

```
var sentence = "Over the candidate behaves the patent Then the doctor.";
var desiredResult = "Over the candidate behaves the patent, then the doctor.";
var pattern = /[a-z]\s[A-Z]/g;
```

I want to a correct sentence by adding comma and a space before a capital other than 'I' if the preceding letter is lowercase.

Comment: It's not really clear what sort of heuristics are supposed to be used to detect the structure; you could just use something like this otherwise; `^.*?(patent\sT).*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.replace()` on your sentence and pass replacing function as second parameter

```
var corrected = sentence.replace(
    /([a-z])\s([A-Z])/g, 
    function(m,s1,s2){  //arguments: whole match (t T), subgroup1 (t), subgroup2 (T)
        return s1+', '+s2.toLowerCase();
    }
);
```

As for preserving uppercased `I`, there are many ways, one of them:

```
var corrected = sentence.replace(
    /([a-z])\s([A-Z])(.)/g, 
    function(m,s1,s2,s3){
        return s1+((s2=='I' && /[^a-z]/i.test(s3))?(' '+s2):(', '+s2.toLowerCase()))+s3;
    }
);
```

But there are more cases when it will fail, like: `His name is Joe.`, `WTF is an acronym for What a Terrible Failure.` and many others.

Comment: I added one more stipulation, "I", I wan't it to leave "I"'s alone. Any ideas?